# Does chef knife ever need to directly access a node?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef, knife, bootstrap

Does `knife` ever access nodes directly, for example, during bootstrapping? Or does bootstrapping (and other access) all go via the chef server?

I'm wondering whether I can get away with configuring firewalls in AWS so that only the chef server can access the WinRM ports on the node (rather than the wide world where my workstation lives).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knife bootstrap, and knife ssh both access directly, but both can take a flag for a jump box. I believe -G is the one.  Of course, that jump box would need to be accessible from your workstation

Comment: Is that jump box usually/necessarily a chef server?

Comment: It certainly doesn't have to be.  And I'd say it's probably better if it isn't.